# Using static embeddings compatible with BERT

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I have a dataset of utterances and corresponding sentiment label. I want to use an embedding of the sentiment label as an additional input to BERT (To simplify things, you can say that I want to initialize the embeddings for some tokens in my BERT model). There are 6-7 unique labels. I planned to use static embeddings like GloVe to map the label to an embedding, but this will not be compatible with BERT, which expects the input embedding to be of size 768. How can I generate static embeddings of my labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can try sbert to generate embedding for both of your sentence and label of given dimension size.
Here is the library - https://www.sbert.net/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you explain how sbert can generate label embeddings?

Comment: Hi @bh00t,  Actually SBERT based on encoder model, has embeddings for tokens in your sentence and whole sentence is represented by a CLS token. So in SBERT, there are different variation of sentence embedding, like using only CLS token, mean pooling of token embedding.